# Mysql to return the table name the id exists in

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a design like this

```
accounts(id, username, email, password, ..)
admin_accounts(account_id, ...)
user_accounts(account_id, ....)
premium_accounts(account_id, ....)
```

id is the primary key in accounts
account_id is a foreign(references id on accounts table) and primary key in these three tables(admin, user, premium)

Knowing the id how can I find which type this user is with only one query? Also knowing that an id can only exists in one of the three tables(admin, user, premium)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `case`:

```
select
  a.id,
  case 
    when aa.account_id is not null then 'admin_accounts'
    when ua.account_id is not null then 'user_accounts'
    when pa.account_id is not null then 'premium_accounts'
  else
    'No detail found'
  end as found_in
from
  accounts a
  left join admin_accounts aa on aa.account_id = a.id
  left join user_accounts ua on ua.account_id = a.id
  left join premium_accounts pa on pa.account_id = a.id
/*where -- In case you want to filter.
  a.id = ....*/
```

using `union`

```
select
  id,
  found_in
from
    (select account_id as id, 'admin_accounts' as found_in 
    from admin_accounts aa 
    union all
    select account_id, 'user_accounts'
    from user_accounts ua 
    union all 
    select account_id, 'premium_accounts'
    from premium_accounts pa) a
/*where -- In case you want to filter.
  a.account_id = ....*/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `UNION` you can try applying a solution proposed here - [mysql return table name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168068/mysql-return-table-name)

Answer (score 0):

You can use union query like

```
(select id, 'admin' as user_type from account inner join admin_accounts) UNION 
(select id, 'user' as user_type from account inner join user_accounts) UNION 
(select id, 'premium' as user_type from account inner join premium_accounts);
```